# How to use the View Transition API (web) for transition elements that are not the same DOM element?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a thumbnail DOM element that needs to transition into the modal DOM element that opens when that thumbnail is clicked. The thumbnail and the modal are NOT the same DOM element. For this I want to use the View Transitions API.

[image: thumbnail-to-modal transition]

The topic of using transition elements that are not the same DOM element is covered in [one of the chapters](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/#transitioning-elements-dont-need-to-be-the-same-dom-element) of the Chrome article "Smooth and simple transitions with the View Transitions API".

I was surprised to find the transition element behave differently from what I expected, when trying to build the thumbnail-to-modal transition. What am I doing wrong?

I have written a simple variant of the code I expected to work in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cgbakker/pen/qBJyrLv).

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="thumbnail">Click me</div>

<div id="modal">You have opened the modal<div id="closer">X</div></div>

<div id="comment">
pink outline = ::view-transition-old<br> green outline = ::view-transition-new"
</div>

/* CSS */
#thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: #74747444;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 80px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#closer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

::view-transition-old(modal),
::view-transition-new(modal) {
  animation-duration: 5s;
}

::view-transition-old(modal) {
  outline: 4px solid pink;
}

::view-transition-new(modal) {
  outline: 4px solid green;
  outline-offset: 4px;
}

// JavaScript
const thumbnail = document.querySelector("#thumbnail")

const modal = document.querySelector("#modal")

const closer = document.querySelector("#closer")

thumbnail.addEventListener("click", () => openModal())

closer.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "none"
})

function openModal() {
  // Fallback for non-supporting browsers
  if (!document.startViewTransition) {
    modal.style.display = "block"
    return
  }
  
  thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"
  modal.style.viewTransitionName = ""

  const transition = document.startViewTransition(() => {
    modal.style.display = "block"
  })
  
  transition.updateCallbackDone.then(() => {
    thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = ""
    modal.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"
  })
  
  transition.finished.finally(() => {
    modal.style.viewTransitionName = ""
  })
}
```

Comment: Nothing sets the transition-name of your #modal element, and you'll want to remove it from #thumbnail when the transition starts.

Comment: But I do both in the openModal() function, right?

Comment: No, you only set it to `""`, which you'll also want to not do by the way.

Comment: I set `thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"` before `document.startViewTransition()`. And `updateCallbackDone` can be used to set the transition name of `::view-transition-new(modal)` as I have done, right?

Comment: Yes, you set `#thumbnail`'s `transitionName`, but not `#modal`'s one. When `updateCallbackDone` resolves it's far too late.

Comment: If `updateCallbackDone` is too late, when exactly is the `view-transition-new` snapshot of the transition element taken? After all code in the callback of `startViewTransition` has executed?

Comment: Well I'm no expert (hence why  didn't post an anwser yet), but logically, to be able to transition from A to B, the engine needs to have both A and B from the beginning of the transition, no?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/view-transitions/#transitioning-elements-dont-need-to-be-the-same-dom-element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving the code `thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = null; modal.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"` from the `updateCallbackDone` promise callback to the `startViewTransition` callback did the trick.

So the new code is as follows (also see [this codepen](https://codepen.io/cgbakker/pen/OJBwoRL)).

```
<div id="thumbnail">Click me</div>

<div id="modal">You have opened the modal<div id="closer">X</div></div>
```

```
#thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid darkred;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: #74747444;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  translate: -50% -50%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 80px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background-color: white;
}

#closer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```
const thumbnail = document.querySelector("#thumbnail")

const modal = document.querySelector("#modal")

const closer = document.querySelector("#closer")

thumbnail.addEventListener("click", () => openModal())

closer.addEventListener("click", () => {
  modal.style.display = "none"
})

function openModal() {
  // Fallback for non-supporting browsers
  if (!document.startViewTransition) {
    modal.style.display = "block"
    return
  }
  
  thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"

  const transition = document.startViewTransition(() => {
    thumbnail.style.viewTransitionName = null
    modal.style.viewTransitionName = "modal"
    modal.style.display = "block"
  })
    
  transition.finished.finally(() => {
    modal.style.viewTransitionName = null
  })
}
```